# Subclass obtained from Serviceloader throws AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, abstract-class, serviceloader

I am trying to make a Java app that can load plugins implementing an abstract class and am having an AbstractMethodError with the instances generated from ServiceLoader. The code is a bit heavy so I've made a simplification below.

First, I have an abstract class:

```
package stuff.TheAbstractClass;

public abstract class TheAbstractClass implements ClassInterface{
 //Stuff happens
}
```

Which implements the below interface:

```
package stuff.ClassInterface;

public interface ClassInterface {

    public String getClassName();

}
```

I have a service provider `NotAbstractClass` which extends `TheAbstractClass` and states so in a meta-inf/services folder:

```
package anotherstuff.NotAbstractClass;

public final class NotAbstractClass extends TheAbstractClass implements ClassInterface{
    private String name = "Silent Bob";

    @Override
    public String getClassName() { return name; }

}
```

Then on the main application (which is actually a plugin inside another application), I want to find all classes which extend `TheAbstractClass`:

```
package stuff.TheApp;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class TheApp {
    private String name;

    public final static TheApp INSTANCE = new TheApp();

    private TheApp() {
        ServiceLoader<TheAbstractClass> serviceLoader =
            ServiceLoader.load(TheAbstractClass.class);
        for (TheAbstractClass class: serviceLoader) {
            name = class.getClassName;
        }
}
```

My application does find `NotAbstractClass`. I know this since, in the for loop, I can do `class.getName()` and it'll give me `anotherstuff.NotAbstractClass`) but gives the error:
`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: stuff.TheAbstractClass.getClassName()Ljava/lang/String;`

I'm stumped. Any suggestion? Thank you, Pedro

Comment: Have you defined your services to be registerd as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#register-service-providers?

Comment: @hotzst, Indeed I have. I know it is loaded since, in the for loop, I can do "class.getName()" and it'll give me "anotherstuff.NotAbstractClass".

Answer (score 0):

According to the API for [AbstractMethodError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html) you get this:

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally,
>   this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run
>   time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since
>   the currently executing method was last compiled.

Just by looking at your code and your comment I see that this could only have happened at runtime.

If that is the case then:

> **some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing**
>   **method was last compiled**

I've tested your logic after some adjustments in a Java compatible form and I had no problems. The only thing that seems to be happening is a change in any of the subclasses of `TheAbstractClass`.

Another thing I did was to declare the dependencies using the dependency files in: resources/META-INF/services:

**file**: <full-package>.TheAbstractClass

**content**: <full-package>.NotAbstractClass

After this I had no problems.

Comment: That seems logical and it's probably the case. However, "some class" is a bit vague in my mind. Neither TheAbstractClass nor the NotAbstractClass are modified in runtime, unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue wasn't in the code, but in the IDE (IntelliJ). I deleted all previously packaged jars and made new jars without changing anything and it magically worked... So it's an IDE bug, and not a language issue!
Thanks to @Joao and @hotzst for taking time to read however.
Best, Pedro